# Why create a class with no constructor and filled with static methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class

I am reading a project with legacy code and I found something like this (simplified here):

```
    class FooUpdater {
        static getData() {}

        static someFunc() {}

        static otherFunc() {}

        static async init() {}
    }
```

I also note that it is never instantiated. The only use it `FooUpdater.init()` in another part of the repo.

Although I won't change this section, I think it is a better alternative to only have an object that contains functions. Something like this:

```
    const FooUpdater = {
        getData: () => {},
        someFunc: () => {},
        otherFunc: () => {},
        init: async () => {}
    };
```

**It has the same result, right?**

**What could be the reason why this person choose a constructorless class filled with static methods, instead of a simple object with functions? Maybe a design pattern, performance or another thing?**

Comment: It's a cheap way to limit namespace pollution, but personally I think it's really ugly.

Comment: It's like an object literal there's no function that is part of the FooUpdater  prototype and new is not required

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Using a class in that way is playing stupid and when I see it it makes my eyes bleed. There are situations where it might make sense to create such a class but only if it were extended. Otherwise an object is clearly superior. The reason that someone would do this, is that they don't understand JavaScript. It's also possible that they don't want to understand it. They really are programmers like that.

Comment: Presumably the developer comes from Java or C# or some such language, so they are writing code as they would in their native language.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It guarantees that the class itself is a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Attempt to run the following:

```
class Foo {}

class Foo {}
```

This will throw (guaranteed by the spec), and your object literal example does not have that property. When you get ahold of `Foo` via importing or whatnot, you know exactly what you get. That being said, I don't like it, Singletons are a [known anti-pattern](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid) in their own right and this is very non-idiomatic for Javascript. You could actually instantiate the class with the default constructor if you really wanted to, but that would be pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks Jared! Do you agree with the comments below the question?  Please update your answer with the data you consider useful (to have the full picture) and I will select it.

Comment: @NicoDiz yes, it's most likely someone coming from Java. In Java classes are the only abstraction you really have, and so it's pretty common to use a class with only static methods purely as a namespace. It's not "wrong" per se, but it isn't necessary in Javascript.

Comment: @JaredSmith a `const` is as much a singleton as a `class` in this context (an arbitrary lexical scope) as evidenced by the equivalence of `const Foo = class {}`